# error in the use of "conflictual"?

Tags: adjectives, grammaticality-in-context

I have written following sentence however not sure if it conveys the idea. Any help would be appreciated.

> No study has yet focused on the conflictual simultaneous representation of post-feminist empowerment narratives, feminist narratives, and self-objectification

Here, I tried to use ***conflictual*** as an adjective to state that simultaneous representation is conflictual. Dictionary says it is ok to use but I am not sure if it is a correct form.

I have checked the ludwig.guru and other similar websites to see if it is used in similar context but could not find examples.

Comment: Can you edit to explain why you think it might be wrong? Showing the dictionary definition of _conflictual_ which you are using might also help.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before asking a question. In this case, you could have looked up the word **conflictual** in a good dictionary. it sounds like the kind of word that 1970's social scientists liked to make up and then misuse. This question will probably be closed: please do your research before asking your next question. A clue: many latin-derived nouns can take -ing and -ual  endings, giving words with subtly different meanings- for example contracting and contractual.

Comment: “I tried to use **conflictual** as an adjective to state that simultaneous representation is **conflictual**.” what do you understand conflictual to mean?

Comment: “If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself.”  - Albert Einstein .  Could you paraphrase your sentence in simpler language?

Comment: @ColleenV I tried to emphasise that representing post-feminist empowerment narratives, feminist narratives, and self-objectification at the same time is something conflictual since these terms are opposite of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Conflictual' means that something is *about* conflict. It does not mean the same as 'conflicting', which describes things that are in conflict, or disagree with one another.

For example:

> The men gave two *conflicting* accounts.

This means that two people gave *differing* accounts that disagreed with one another on one or more points. The accounts could be about any subject.

> The men gave two *conflictual* accounts.

This means that the two men gave accounts *about* a conflict.

---

If you mean that your three list items (post-feminist empowerment narratives, feminist narratives, and self-objectification) are conflicting narratives (they do not agree with one another), then you mean to use the word '*conflicting*':

> No study has yet focused on the conflicting simultaneous representation of post-feminist empowerment narratives, feminist narratives, and self-objectification.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation!